How can i add another panel into a Rex ScrollablePanel when click a button?
Basically, i want to create a mini chat dialog, when i type and click send, it will display into a scrollable table.
First i add an click event:
 this.dialogChatInput.addListener("click");
    this.dialogChatInput.on("click", (event) => {
      if (event.target.id === "sendButton") {
        var inputChat = this.dialogChatInput.getChildByName("nameFieldChat");

        if (inputChat.value !== "") {
          console.log(`Chat : ${inputChat.value}`);
          
        }
      }
    });

Then i try to create an srcrollable table:
var panel = this.rexUI.add
      .scrollablePanel({
        x: this.dialogKhungHienThi.x + 225,
        y: this.dialogKhungHienThi.y,
        height: 1200,

        scrollMode: 0,

        background: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle({
          // strokeColor: transparent,
          strokeWidth: 2,
        }),
        panel: {
          child: CreatePanel(this),
        },

        slider: {
          track: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle({
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            radius: 40,
            color: COLOR_TRACK,
          }),
          thumb: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle({
            radius: 50,
            color: COLOR_THUMB,
          }),
        },

        space: { panel: 4 },
      })
      .layout();

Outside Create() i have function to create panel:
var CreatePanel = function (scene, data) {
  var panel = scene.rexUI.add.sizer({
    width: 100,
    orientation: "y",
    space: { item: 4 },
  });

  if (ngu) {
    var name = `item-${i}`;
    var label = scene.rexUI.add.label(
      {
        height: 350,
        width: 1000,
        background: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle({
          // color: COLOR_PRIMARY,
        }),
        icon: scene.add.image(0, 0, "avatarDemo").setScale(2),
        text: scene.add
          .text(10, 10, ` ${hour} :  ${minute}: ${second} `, {
            font: "70px Arial",
            fill: "#ffffff",
            stroke: "black",
            strokeThickness: 15,
          })
          .setFontSize("70px"),
        wrapText: true,
        name: name,
      },
      this
    );
    panel.add(label, { expand: true });
  }

  return panel;
};

i try to move my var panel inside onclick() but it didnt work? Can anybody have any suggestion?

Well the easy solution is to create a funciton on the scene, that you can call from the button - event. Something like this addLine.
And in the function you simply add a control to the panel, and update the layout of the surrounding controls.

There might be better solutions, but this is the first that comes to mind.

Short Demo:


/* let button = document.querySelector('#button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Depending on how many scenes you are using you would have to change this line
    game.scene.scenes[0].addLine('Button Click');
});*/

class Demo extends Phaser.Scene {
    preload() {
        this.load.scenePlugin({
            key: 'rexuiplugin',
            url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexuiplugin.min.js',
            sceneKey: 'rexUI'
        });
    }
    create() {
        this.textPanel = CreatePanel(this);
        this.chatBox = this.rexUI.add
            .scrollablePanel({
                x: config.width / 2 + 50,
                y: config.height / 2,
                width: 380,
                height: 160,
                background: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 2, 2, 10, 0xcdcdcd),
                scrollMode: 0,
                scroller: true,
                panel: {
                    child: this.textPanel,
                },
                slider: {
                    track: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 20, 10, 10, 0xffffff),
                    thumb: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0x0),
                },
                space: {
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    top: 10,
                    bottom: 10,
                    panel: 10,
                }
            })
            .layout();

        this.addLine('Enter Text and press the Button');
    }

    // function to add Lines
    addLine(text) {
        let newLineControl = this.rexUI.add.label({
            orientation: 1,
            text: this.add.text(0, 0, text),
            expandTextWidth: true,
        });
        this.textPanel.add(newLineControl);

        // You have to re-layout every wrapping control
        this.textPanel.layout();
        this.chatBox.layout();
        
        this.demoDOMElements();
    }
    
    demoDOMElements(){
        let textbox = this.add.dom(4, 4, 'input', 'width: 100px; font: 16px Arial')
            .setOrigin(0);
        textbox.node.valiue = "Initial Text";
        let button = this.add.dom(4, 30, 'button', 'width: 100px; font: 16px Arial', 'Add Line')
            .setOrigin(0);

        button.addListener('click');
        button.on('click', function (event){
          this.addLine(textbox.node.value);
        }, this);
        
    }
}

var CreatePanel = function (scene, data) {
    var panel = scene.rexUI.add.sizer({
        width: 100,
        orientation: "y",
        space: { item: 4 },
    });
    return panel;
};

var config = { width: 510, height: 180, scene: Demo, parent: 'phaser', dom: {
        createContainer: true
    }};

// globale Variabel for Phaser GameObject
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
<!-- <button id="button"> add Line </button> -->
<br />
<div id="phaser"></div>




The problem is my html is create inside scene from add.dom, not outside, and i want to get text from an input and put it in my scrollable panel

@NguyễnHảiLong Well how the html is created is not relevant, you just need to call the function addLine on click, and than pass the value from input box, as a parameter.

I just added the button for the demo, to make it easy to follow and test.

When i try to do the same as you, my console display TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener').  Can you tell me when do i do wrong

Well as mention before the solution is creating the method and using it, and the button I create was for the demo.  You would have to use your code to call the method. Nevertheless I updated the demo to match more your situation. I think from here you should be able to apply it to your code.
